# React admin pass a className to custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I got a `datagrid` in a react admin project with a custom button, and since it's in a a `datagrid`, the button is wrapped into a `td` tag, how can I target this `td` wrapping my button, I tried giving him a `className1 but it's telling me I can't because` type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CreateOrganizationButtonProps`, how is the rule in react? Can't I assign a component of mine a` className`? And how to target this special` td` created by react admin?

```
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  TopToolbar,
  CreateButton,
  ExportButton,
  TextInput,
  useRecordContext,
  useListController,
  ListContextProvider,
} from "react-admin";

import OrganizationsPanel from "./components/organizations-list-panel";
import CreateOrganizationButton from "./components/create-organization-button";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const ListActions = () => (
  <TopToolbar>
    <CreateButton />
    <ExportButton />
  </TopToolbar>
);
const organizationsFilters = [<TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />];

export const OrganizationsList = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <List
      className="custom-list"
      {...props}
      filters={organizationsFilters}
      filter={{ parentOrganizationId: localStorage.getItem("oid") }}
      sx={{
        "& .RaList-content": {
          boxShadow: "none",
        },
      }}
      actions={<ListActions />}
    >
      <Datagrid
        className="custom-list-grid"
        rowClick="edit"
        sx={{
          "& .RaDatagrid-row": {
            border: "none",
            width: "100%",
          },
          "& .RaDatagrid-row:hover .create-organization-button": {
            visibility: "inherit",
          },
          "& .RaDatagrid-row .create-organization-button": {
            visibility: "inherit",
          },
        }}
        bulkActionButtons={false}
        expand={<OrganizationsPanel />}
      >
        <TextField source="name" />
        <CreateOrganizationButton className='salut'/>
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircleOutline";
import { useRecordContext } from "react-admin";

const CreateOrganizationButton: React.FC<CreateOrganizationButtonProps> =
  () => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    return (
      <IconButton
        className="create-organization-button"
        component={Link}
        to={{
          pathname: "/organizations/create",
          search: `?source=${JSON.stringify({
            parentOrganizationId: record.id,
          })}`,
        }}
        sx={{
          position: "relative",
          top: 0,
        }}
        onClick={(event: any) => event.stopPropagation()}
      >
        <AddCircleOutlineIcon color="primary" />
      </IconButton>
    );
  };

interface CreateOrganizationButtonProps {}

export default CreateOrganizationButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `CreateOrganizationButton` component, you have defined what props are expected to be passed in.

```
const CreateOrganizationButton: React.FC<CreateOrganizationButtonProps>
```

The above line means that `CreateOrganizationButton` is of type `React.FC` and it expects to receive `CreateOrganizationButtonProps`.

You've defined `CreateOrganizationButtonProps` as:

```
interface CreateOrganizationButtonProps {}
```

The above line means `CreateOrganizationButtonProps` is expected to be an empty object. You probably want to change it to something like this:

```
interface CreateOrganizationButtonProps {
    className: string;
}
```

Now you should stop getting the error you were seeing. But there's one more step to actually make the `className` you are passing in do something.

You will want to use the `className` you are passing in somehow.

First we want to get the `className` from the `props` in `CreateOrganizationButton`. You can do that using [prop destructuring](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-basics-of-destructuring-props-in-react-a196696f5477/):

```
const CreateOrganizationButton: React.FC<CreateOrganizationButtonProps> =
  ({ className }) => {
...
```

Currently the `<IconButton>` inside your `CreateOrganizationButton` already has a `className` of `"create-organization-button"`. You can change this to the `className` you are passing in to use that instead:

```
      <IconButton
        className={className}
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! So my other question about this is: If i get it right, the childs of datagrid are automatically wrapped into a td element, how can i select one of this ones in CSS otherwise than with a nth:child ? Or to be more precise, how can i add a class or an id to it ?

Comment: One of the components you are using is creating that td, so you just need to apply the correct css to that component. It looks like it might be the IconButton component, but you'd have to double check